# Loading a PHP Contact Form Into an Iframe that is on a Seperate HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, contact-form

if someone could help me with this I'd appreciate it.

Goal:

To have my Contact page have only html / css, with a contact form that is written in php inside an iframe on the page. I'd like the contact page to be myurl.com/contact.HTML not /contact.PHP so I'm using an iframe.

I have the contact form written in PHP and it's functional on it's own when I go to myurl.com/contactform.php but when I put it inside an iframe it gives me a 404 error where the contact form should be. contactform.php is in the public_html folder.

It's saying:

Not Found

The requested URL /public_html/contactform.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I'm assuming the latter error is just the result of my editing the error page, I'll tweak that later.

So what do I do?

If there's a better way to do this I'm all for it. Just trying to keep it all HTML and CSS. note: I just picked coding up again after a few years, so treat me like a newb. 8)

Comment: Rather than using an iframe, why not look into using AJAX. This will allow you to send data to a server-side page/script without moving the client from the current page meaning clients can post data from contact.html to contact.php without being redirected.

Comment: Is your page contact.php or contactform.php? Your saying when you go to contact.php in your browser it works but your error says contactform.php wasn't found...

Comment: @NewToJS With AJAX will I have to re-write the entire form?

Comment: @blazerunner44 Updated the post. The working page is contactform.php that isn't showing up on contact.html

Comment: @Evon, no you won't have to rewrite the form at all. All you will need is the form on the contact.html page and use ajax to submit it to contact.php. Just have the php script on the contact.php page and have it return something so the client has a reply.

Comment: @Evon take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp w3 have some examples of using ajax. It's very simple and much better than redirecting the client to a different page or having to reload the same page.

Comment: @NewToJS Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the

```
<form action="contact.php">
```

in contact.html.
Then process the form in that separate contact.php form.

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: no prob.  If it helped, can you mark it as the correct answer pls.  Im trying to build the reputation score. :)